# Vaadin 14 grid column width on mobile devices

Tags: vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I'm using vaadin 14 TLS. I need to show data in a grid. Everything works fine on the desktop version however, on the mobile devices, column headers are so narrow and they are not readable as only some initials are shown, and there are many columns. The grid itself fits in the page width, so i can scroll to the right and to the left, however, i want each column to take up more space so that each column header is readable without shortened. Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Grids are not a good fit for mobile applications. But you could try to set the min-width of each grid column

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks Simon,     grid.getColumns().forEach(e -> e.setAutoWidth(true));
made the trick, upon some closer look right before reading your comment :)

Comment: Greate. Please add this as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 grid.getColumns().forEach(e -> e.setAutoWidth(true));
```

does the trick.